# Emoji picker on Fedora 35

Tags: fedora, emoji

Is there an emoji picker available on Fedora 35? I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Application called *Characters* (package `gnome-characters` is part of the default workstation installation).

[image]

And in native GNOME applications you can also use the context (right click) menu option *Insert Emoji*.

[image]

You can install tool called *Emoji Picker* (package `emoji-picker`).

Comment: thanks. So in order to use the Characters package, I need to find the emoji and copy it. Do you know if it's searchable?

And do you know if there's the ability to do "Inert Emoji" for non-GNOME applications, like the web browsers or terminal? Is that what _Emoji Picker_ can do?